# Delphi. TIdHTTP Post not updating the file. Put gets 405

Tags: http, delphi, post

I need to update my counter.txt file on my host.

I am using some code I found here: [How to download a file with progress with IdHTTP via https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457925/how-to-download-a-file-with-progress-with-idhttp-via-https) , modified a little bit.

Post does not update the file. Put gets a 405 error- method not allowed.

Will someone please review this and possibly point out why it is not updating the counter?

The counter filee is here:   aFileURL= 'http://greatdaydan.com/Counter.txt';

```
procedure TIdHTTPProgress.DownloadFile(const aFileUrl: string; const aDestinationFile: String);
var
  LDestStream: TFileStream;
  aPath: String;
begin

  Progress := 0;
  FBytesToTransfer := 0;
  aPath := ExtractFilePath(aDestinationFile);
  if aPath <> '' then
    ForceDirectories(aPath);

  LDestStream := TFileStream.Create(aDestinationFile, fmCreate);
  try
    Get(aFileUrl, LDestStream);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LDestStream);
  end;
  FFinished := True;
end;

procedure TIdHTTPProgress.UploadFile(const aFileUrl, aDestinationFile: String);
var
  fs: TFileStream;
  Response: TStringStream;
  Reply: String;
begin
  fs := TFileStream.Create(aDestinationFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  Response := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    post(aFileUrl, fs, Response);
    Reply := Response.DataString
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fs);
    Response.Free;
  end;
  FFinished := True;
end;
```

Comment: I would call just Free to filestreams

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. What does your hosting server **require** you to use to upload files? Does it even support upload via HTTP? If so, does it require you to login before uploading? Clearly HTTP `PUT` is not allowed, but HTTP `POST` may not be the correct solution, either. What about FTP?

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result by using FTP to upload the file.